# How to add Date Picker in Horizontal paging scroll view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, ios5

I have Created UIScrollview with Paging, But i want to add Date picker in some pages. But Date picker scroll not working.

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,100,100,100);

    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:myPicker];
    [myPicker release];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    [subview release];
}

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = colors.count;
```

Comment: Date Picker scroll not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the picker view to `self.view`, add it to `self.scrollView`

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:myPicker];
```

Or else, You can add picker view as input view to a text field,

```
for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
    //CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,100,100,100);

    myTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:
                                CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 30)]; //if you dont want to show the text field you can change the frame to CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    myTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    myTextField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:myTextField];

    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [myTextField setInputView:myPicker];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:myTextField];


    [myPicker release];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    [subview release];
}
```

and when you want to show the picker, Call the below method `[self showPickerView]`

```
- (void)showPickerView
{
    [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```